# Could not find driver error

Tags: server, php, mysql, php7

When I try to run `index.php` using this command -

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

I get `"could not find driver"` *error*.

But `php` files not using `mysql` runs correctly. What may be the issue and how do I fix this?

I am using **Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit**.
Please refer to the following outputs-

https://paste.ubuntu.com/17427857/

https://paste.ubuntu.com/17427866/

Comment: Also, please remove the apache2 tag. This is not related to it, because you are running the internal PHP server.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the php7.0-mysql package.

So you should install the php7.0-mysql package.

*PS: Why are you downvoting this? It has solved OP's problem.*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/580360)

Comment: After installing the above package now i get this error- SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'.  I haven't set any password for root. how do i reset this password?

Comment: @Videonauth so much clearer, now!

Comment: @ShikharKunal now you have installed the driver, and your error is a different one. The root password was setup during MySql installation. If you don't remember that, you need to reconfigure it. Here is a resource to do that: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset